# Datatable.Load doesn't remove deleted rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable, sqldatareader

I am facing a problem when reading data from SQL Server database to a Datatable. I am using a Datatable as datasource for my DataGridView and use the following code to fill the datatable from the SQL Server table. this code runs every 10 seconds to keep the results updated and works fine when rows are modified or added (from another instance of the program or directly from ssms), but when rows are removed from the db they stay in the datatable.

For example, if I initially load the table with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Table
```

and then load it with

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM Table
```

the datatable would still have 10 rows.

I tried every `LoadOptions` (Upsert, OverwriteChanges and PreserveChanges) same result.

The only solution I found is to call `datatable.Rows.Clear()` before loading, but it causes other problems.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dt.Load(reader);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you just create a new DataTable? dt = new DataTable();

Comment: I can but then I will need to reset the datagridview's datasource. it seemed not right.. if it's ok so I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're going to have to reset the datagridview's datasource either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't isue. This works in that way.
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Fills a DataTable with values from a data source using the supplied
>   IDataReader. If the DataTable already contains rows, the incoming data
>   from the data source is merged with the existing rows.

You can create new datatable or clear existing by [Restet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.reset(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> Resets the DataTable to its original state. Reset removes all data,
>   indexes, relations, and columns of the table. If a DataSet includes a
>   DataTable, the table will still be part of the DataSet after the table
>   is reset.

So your code:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```

Can look like:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Reset();
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: I added the Reset() as you suggested and a weird messagebox exception appeared even though the app ran in debug mode. the message said index out of range. maybe because a data grid view has the datatable as its datasource?